# Initiate TinyMCE on a jQuery Mobile website

Tags: jquery-mobile, tinymce

I'm trying to initiate TinyMCE with a jQuery mobile website.

This is my head for javascript sourcing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/styler.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/mainstyle.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('.close-notification').click(
        function () {
            $(this).parent().fadeTo(350, 0, function () {
                $(this).slideUp(600);
            });
            return false;
        }
    );

    $(document).live( 'pageinit',function(event) {
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode:"textareas",
            theme:"advanced",
            theme_advanced_buttons1:"bold,italic,bullist,numlist",
            theme_advanced_buttons2:"",
            theme_advanced_buttons3:"",
            theme_advanced_buttons4:"",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location:"top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align:"left",
            theme_advanced_resizing:false
        });
    });

</script>
```

Ok, so I then have a textarea like so

```
<textarea name="message" style="width:100%" tabindex="3" rows="10" id="wysiwyg"></textarea>
```

But the textarea is not being replaced with a TinyMCE iframe. No errors are reported to console.

Comment: Is the pageinit getting called ? If not use pagebeforeshow or pageshow

Comment: Ok, I've basically got it working, however, it is only working when the page is accessed directly, not using an internal link. pageinit is getting called.

Comment: Nope, it's not working. Only way to get it to work is by removing the live wrapped to the init. And it's still limited.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile actually applies styles and classes to input elements, and in some cases actually replaces them with programmatically created elements that it has complete control over. I'd inspect the textarea you see on the page and see if it's the same one you're targeting. You can even run commands in the console such as setting the background of your intended target to check to see if it's the one you're looking at.

You might also try accessing the "pagebeforecreate" event so that you can get the "real" textarea before jQuery Mobile gets it's hooks into it.

Answer (score 0):

For Jquery Mobile what i do (and it runs):

```
<script>
$(document).live( 'pagebeforecreate',function(event){
    if($('textarea.tinymce').length){
            $(document).bind('pagebeforeshow',function(event) {
                tinyMCE.init({
                // General options
                mode : "textareas",
                selector : "textarea.tinymce",
                theme : "simple"
            });
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Make sure you have loaded tiny before this. you can load it dinamically just first time:

```
if(typeof TinyMCE == "undefined") {
    $.getScript('tinymce.js');
}
```

Note: I have it in each page and fires tiny each time textarea with class i detected, but load script just once